# SQL Database error in vBulletin 4.1.4

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can anyone please help me why I am getting these type of errors? Is there something wrong with the SQL or what? I am a newbie with these codes so can anyone please help me out?

```
Database error in vBulletin 4.1.4:

Invalid SQL:

                                       SELECT * FROM rsslog
                                       WHERE uniquehash IN ('HASHCODE', 'ANOTHERHASHCODE');

MySQL Error   : MySQL server has gone away
Error Number  : 2006
Request Date  : Saturday, February 11th 2012 @ 04:31:31 PM
Error Date    : Saturday, February 11th 2012 @ 04:32:56 PM
Script        : http://mydomain.com/cron.php?rand=1328977887
Referrer      : http://mydomain.com/education-careers/2768-mercy-crops-pakistan-jobs-2012-02-05-2012-05-26-am/
IP Address    : 74.125.16.158
Username      : Unregistered
Classname     : vB_Database
MySQL Version :
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that your client could not connect to the MySQL server. This can have many reasons. They are explained in the [official documentation on this error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html).